# Toad 9.7.2 for Oracle hangs on Windows 7

Tags: oracle, windows, toad

I am using Toad 9.7.2 on Windows 7 64 bit.

It is generally working fine but there is one problem. When I click on certain tables in "Schema Browser" and then click on "Data" tab to see records in them then Toad hangs.

This is only happening for some tables and most of them are working fine. If I run SELECT query to retrieve data from those problemetic tables then it also runs fine. Problem only happens when I try to view records by clicking on "Data" tab.

I thought may those tables contain huge number of records but that's not the case. One of the table only contain 25 records but still Toad still hangs and then I have to kill the process.

Any idea why this is happening and how to solve this?

**EDIT**

Found one clue. This is only happening for those tables which have Parent table.

You know there is another tab called "Referential" which shows both Child Tables i.e. "table is referenced by" and Parent Tables "table references". So if a table has parent table then Toad hangs when I click on "Data" tab for that table.

Comment: what version of oracle are you connecting to?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue by going into `Configure TOAD Options --> Schema Browser --> Data and Grids` and there I unchecked `Enable FK Lookup`